# Last Element in For Loop Not Iterating Completely

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iteration, counter

I'm having an issue with one of my assignments where I'm using a for loop to compare two lists, one being an answer key, and the other being a list of student answers, to produce a score where +4 is given for correct responses, -1 for incorrect, and 0 for omitted responses. It's working fine until it gets to the last element of the loop. I know the program is "reading" the last elements, because I've had it print them before, but it's not adjusting the score correctly, and is actually subtracting a point, regardless of the answer. I can't figure out what's going wrong, especially since it's only the last part that does this.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    #As we go over each line, we add to the student counter to keep track of the number of students.
    #We use the split function to turn each line of the file into a list that we can use.
    for line in open_file:
        students += 1
        student_ans = line.split(",")

        #The score tracker keeps track of total score.
        score_tracker = 0

        #This for loop iterates over each value in the list, comparing to the answer key.
        for n in range(number_ans):
            a = answerkey[n]
            b = student_ans[n+1]

            #A series of if/elif/else statements give and take points according to answers.
            if a == b:
                score_tracker += 4
            elif b == "":
                score_tracker += 0
            else: 
                score_tracker -= 1
        print(score_tracker)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to add an appropriate tag for your language.

Comment: Is it the last student that doesn't process, or the last score for each student?  If you run just the code snippet above (with an appropriate file open) do you still get the problem?  Is there a `traceback`?

Comment: It's both actually, which has been a concern. I've been able to solve the issue of the last student not processing by repeating the "score_tracker" for loop outside of the original for loop (because the program is reading the last student, just don't going through the rest of the loop with it).

I'm very new to programming though, so I don't know what you mean by traceback. A google search suggests to me it lists what the program is doing, how do I access that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between me and my professor, we've figured out what was wrong. Turns out the last element in each line of the file contained "\n" to bring it to a new line, and I hadn't thought to get rid of it because it didn't stop the code from printing out the two correct answers, only from correctly adding the score. (The computer saw D and Dn\, but showed me D and D for the final answers on the answer key.

I suppose the lesson in this for me is to always look at what the computer sees, which is not necessarily what I see.

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure how to do that. But I'll keep looking around the page.